# Is it necessary to show that if x = y then f(x) = f(y)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $a, \beta, \gamma \in \ell_\infty$ be fixed sequences. For a sequence $b$ define $$T(b_n) = a_n + \beta_n b_{n+1} + \gamma_n b_{n+2}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}.$$ Prove that $T$ is a well-defined continuous mapping from $\ell_\infty$ to $\ell_\infty$.

---

I have proved that $T$ is continuous. My question is about well-definedness: what exactly do I need to show?

I have shown already that $Tb \in \ell_\infty$ for $b \in \ell_\infty$. Is that all that is necessary here?

I know that sometimes it is necessary to show that if $b = c$, then $Tb = Tc$. But in this case, that sort of proof seems unnecessary. If I did have to show that, I would simply say, "Assume $b = c$. Then for each $n$, we know that $b_{n+1} = c_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+2} = c_{n+2}$. So $T(b_n) = a_n + \beta_n b_{n+1} + \gamma_n b_{n + 2} = a_n + \beta_n c_{n+1} + \gamma_n c_{n + 2} = T(c_n)$. So, because $T(b_n) = T(c_n)$ for all $n$, $Tb = Tc$." Is that necessary? Thanks!

**Edit:**

In response to one of the comments, here is more context for this question. It is routine to have different ways of representing the same input for a function, and you have to check that the different possible representations nevertheless map to the same output. For example, any rational number $x = a/b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by the rule $f(x) = (a+1)/(b+1)$. Then $f$ is not a function because $1/2 = 2/4$ and yet $f(1/2) = 2/3$ while $f(2/4) = 3/5$. In this example, the pathology arises because $f$ is defined in such a way that it implicitly dissects $x$ into its components and acts on the components.

The reason this is on my mind is that the function $T$ takes a sequence, and yet $T$ is defined based on how it acts on the individual components of that sequence. So, $T$ has in common with my pathological $f$ that these functions are defined based on how they act on the individual components of some input. With $f$, it is necessary and nontrivial to check that if $x = y$ then $f(x) = f(y)$, and in the case of $f$, this leads to pathology. So I wanted to ask Stack Exchange whether or not this sort of check is always necessary when a function is defined based on how it acts on the individual components of an input.

In this case, if you choose $x, y \in \ell_\infty$ and $x = y$, then it is obvious that $T(x_n) = T(y_n)$, for an individual component. So a specific version of my question in this case would be: Is demonstrating that an arbitrary component $T(x_n) = T(y_n)$ the same as demonstrating that $T(x) = T(y)$? I had discussed with some of my peers that maybe an induction would be necessary to make the leap from $T(x_n) = T(y_n)$ for "an arbitrary $n$" to $T(x_n) = T(y_n)$ for "all values of $n$".

Comment: You only have to show that $Tb \in \ell^{\infty}$ whenever $b \in \ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: The title is weird. Of cours if $x=y$, you can replace *everywhere* $x$ by $y$, so $f(x)=f(y)$...

Comment: For $T: B \to D$. the only time you need to show $b = c \implies Tb = Tc$ is if $Tx$ has not been defined directly in terms of $x$, but rather, in terms of some representation of $x$. That is, there is some set $A$ of "representations" and some known functions $r : A \to B, T' : A \to D$ with $r$ surjective. And $T$ is defined by $T(r(a)) = T'(a)$ for all $a \in A$. Then it is necessary to show that if $r(a_1) = r(a_2)$, then $T'(a_1) = T'(a_2)$. Despite some sloppy notation in your question, that is not the case here.

Comment: As an example, suppose you tried to define $N : (0,1) \to \Bbb N$ by "let $0.b_1b_2\dots$ be the binary expansion of $t$. Then $N(t)$ is the least $i$ with $b_i = 1$." This is not well defined because $N$ is defined not in terms of $t$ itself, but rather in terms of its binary expansion. But if $t$ is rational with least denominator a power of $2$, then it will have two binary expansions, with different values of $N$. Had $N$ been defined directly from $t$ instead of binary expansions, there would have been no problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Incredibly helpful response. Thank you. You say, "Despite some sloppy notation..." My friends and I spent literally all day yesterday on this question (though it does have other parts), and I suspected throughout our struggle that part of the difficulty came from the notation. But I never could put my finger on exactly what I didn't like about the notation. So I am wondering if you can comment on what specifically is sloppy about the notation and how it might be improved?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think your two comments are an answer. Anyone searching for something similar to that titles will appreciate your example.

Comment: What I found sloppy is that $T$ is a map on sequences, but it is defined as if it were a map from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. A better choice would have been $$T((b_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}) = (a_n + \beta_n b_{n+1} + \gamma_n b_{n+2})_{n \in \Bbb N}$$

Comment: @LukasBetz - I had put it as a comment because I thought I was addressing only a sidepoint to the question. But looking it over again, it does appear to be what they were after. I'll add it when I have more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from comments - with some expansion - since it answers the central question.)

If you define a map $F : A \to B$ directly from the elements of $A$, it is not necessary to prove that if $x = y$, then $F(x) = F(y)$. The mechanics of your definition take care of that automatically. Where you need to prove $x = y \implies F(x) = F(y)$ is when $F$ is not defined directly on elements of $A$, but rather from some representation of those elements.

For example, you might attempt to define $F: (0,1) \to \Bbb N$ by

> for $t\in (0,1)$, let $0.b_1b_2b_3\dots$ be the binary expansion of $t$, then $F(t) = \min\{i : b_i = 1\}$.

This doesn't define $F$ in terms of $t$ itself, but rather its binary expansion. And the problem is, some $t$ have more than one binary expansion (in particular, those $t\ne 0$ with $2^kt\in \Bbb Z$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$).

More generally, if there is some set $C$ of "representations" and a surjective map $r : C \to A$ carrying each representation to the element of $A$ that it represents, and there is some mapping $\tilde F : C \to A$, and the definition of $F$ is effectively

> For all $c \in C, F(r(c)) = \tilde F(c)$.

Then, it is necessary to show "when $x = y, F(x) = F(y)$". Because what you are actually showing is that when $r(x) = r(y), \tilde F(x) = \tilde F(y)$.

In my example, $C=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is the set of all binary sequences $(b_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ (for notational convenience, using $0\notin \Bbb N$). $r$ is the function interpreting these sequences as binary expansions of real numbers. In particular,
$$r((b_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{2^i}$$ And $$\tilde F((b_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}) = \min \{i : b_i = 1\}.$$

Alas, since $r(1\overline 0) = r(0\overline 1) = \frac 12$, but $\tilde F(1\overline 0) =1$ while $\tilde F(0\overline 1) = 2$, this $F$ is not well-defined.